# Add features to ckeditor for add button and other objects to editor in laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

good day. We have a ckedtior. Now, if you have noticed, in places like WordPress, it is possible to add special buttons or objects in the editor. I wanted to see what the solution is. Now, if there is no plugin for it, please give me a solution to write the code. It will be a great help. Thanks, I have attached a picture so you can see it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjtP.png)

Finally, if you can introduce me a plugin or give me a way to code it, I would be grateful